# replace a dynamic shared library in run time

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I need to use different dynamic library over a execution cycle of a program. Looking at `dlfcn.h` I thought this was possible. I confess of not reading much literature on dynamic library loading.

OK here is what I do -

- I have created shared library called `libdynamicTest.so.1`

  The main APP opens this solib (**dlopen**), gets the function pointer (**dlsym**), run it and then close it back (**dlclose**)

Everything is fine until here.

- Now suppose I replace my libdynamicTest.so.1 by another libdynamicTest.so.1 (some code diff) I see a Segmentation fault. Further I have made sure the solib is replaced after **dlclose** and before **dlopen**.

Can someone explain why this segmentation fault ?

I noticed even if I delete libdynamicTest.so.1 the program still executes, quiet strange.

```
    SysTrace(("opening dynamic library"));
    handle = dlopen("libdynamicTest.so.1",RTLD_LAZY);
    fn     = dlsym (handle,"dylib_print_msg");
    SysTrace(("Using dynamic library"));
    if(!fn)
    {
        printf("unknown dylib_print_msg..!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        (*fn)();
    }
    ret = dlclose(handle);
    SysTrace(("closed dynamic library status = [%s]", (ret==0?"OK":"NOK")));
```

P.S. I am not trying to modify the behavior of any existing program, nor pose any threat. I was doing a feasibility check to run integration tests as shared libraries.

---

edit

I tried with gdb, following is the stack trace, when the fault occurred.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003e92408b7b in check_match.8509 () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#0  0x0000003e92408b7b in check_match.8509 ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x0000003e92409024 in do_lookup_x () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x0000003e92409222 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x0000003e92908f14 in do_sym () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000003e93001104 in dlsym_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#5  0x0000003e9240ced6 in _dl_catch_error ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000003e9300150d in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#7  0x0000003e930010ba in dlsym () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
```

---

edit

code base shared at svn checkout `http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/dynamic_libso`

---

edit :- added logs LD_DEBUG=all

```
32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__libc_start_main' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:
     32564:     initialize program: ./test_agent
     32564:
     32564:
     32564:     transferring control: ./test_agent
     32564:
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `printf' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `putchar' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
-hello.c main():20 Msg : hello world ..!!
-hello.c main():24 Msg : opening dynamic library
     32564:     symbol=dlopen;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=dlopen;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `dlopen' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:     opening file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]; direct_opencount=1
     32564:
     32564:     symbol=dlerror;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=dlerror;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `dlerror' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
-hello.c main():26 Msg : Opened dynamic library handle = [a16d9000]
     32564:     symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=dlsym;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `dlsym' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:     symbol=_dl_sym;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=_dl_sym;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     symbol=_dl_sym;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     symbol=_dl_sym;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     32564:     binding file /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_dl_sym' [GLIBC_PRIVATE]
     32564:     symbol=solib_print_msg;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     binding file /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0] to /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `solib_print_msg'
-hello.c main():28 Msg : Using dynamic library
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     32564:     binding file /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `printf' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     symbol=putchar;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
     32564:     binding file /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `putchar' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
-dynamic.c solib_print_msg():9 Msg : nice nice..!!
     32564:     symbol=dlclose;  lookup in file=./test_agent [0]
     32564:     symbol=dlclose;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
     32564:     binding file ./test_agent [0] to /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `dlclose' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
     32564:
     32564:     closing file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1; direct_opencount=0
-hello.c main():40 Msg : closed dynamic library status = [OK]
-hello.c main():24 Msg : opening dynamic library
     32564:     opening file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]; direct_opencount=1
     32564:
-hello.c main():26 Msg : Opened dynamic library handle = [0]
     32564:     symbol=solib_print_msg;  lookup in file=/user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]
     32564:     binding file /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0] to /user/skm/coding/fTest/approach/dynamic_library/gravity/contribs/libs/libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `solib_print_msg'
-hello.c main():28 Msg : Using dynamic library
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You're looking up a new function pointer with `dlsym()` after opening the new library, right?  Not re-using the old pointer?

Comment: Yes new function pointer every time. I have updated a small code snippet for reference.

Comment: Deleting a file does not remove the file from any process space that has an open file pointer to it. As soon as all processes with open file pointers terminate, the data read from the now deleted file will be deleted as well.

Comment: So when you say you replace the library, is that while the program is running, or while not?

Comment: The above code snippet is running in a while loop. After dlclose() there is a delay of 5 secs. That's when I am replacing the shared library. So yes when replacing the library the program is being run.

Comment: I need to ask: why do you need to do that? Didn't you code the program or are you trying to hack/cheat your way into some 3rd party application?

Comment: Look in /proc/###/maps after the dlclose and see if the .so is gone?

Comment: @karlphillip - nope my intention is not to hack/cheat, its intended to run integration tests for our own software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From "man dlclose":

```
The function dlclose() decrements the reference count on the dynamic
library handle handle.  If the reference count drops to zero and
no other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library
is unloaded.
```

I am guessing that you are running afoul of the **"no other loaded libraries use symbols in it"** part.

To debug, run your program with `LD_DEBUG=bindings`, and look for messages like:

```
binding file <some.so> [0] to libdynamicTest.so.1 [0]: normal symbol `<symbol>'
```

Update:

You have several bugs:

1. You are linking `test_agent` against `libdynamic.so.1` **directly**:
   `cc -o test_agent -L. ...-ldl build/test_agent/hello.o libdynamic.so.1`

   Once you've done this, you can no longer expect this library to be *ever* unloaded.
2. By doing this:

   `*((int *)handle) = 0;`

   you are actually corrupting the state of the dynamic loader, and *that* causes subsequent `dlsym` to give you bogus address, which causes your `SIGSEGV` when you try to use it.

Once you fix problem #2, your program will no longer crash, though it will still not unload the library. To *actually* get the library to unload, you need to also fix problem #1.

If you fix problem #1 first, then problem #2 will no longer corrupt the dynamic loader. It will corrupt heap instead, and you can trivially observe that with Valgrind.

Comment: If reference count to solib handle that you mentioned is same as direct_opencount from the logs, then its working as expected. Is there any way to confirm if solib is unloaded ? The program is behaving as though "handle = dlopen("libdynamicTest.so.1",RTLD_LAZY);" has effect only for first run.

Answer (score 2):

According to `man 8 ld.so`:

```
BUGS
       Currently ld.so has no means of unloading and searching for com‐
       patible or newer version of libraries.
```

I'm not 100% sure this is related, but it sounds like it may be.

Comment: I am getting nuts on this, I see the program is crashing if dlopen handler is modified after dlclose is executed.